# @reboot crontab has no effect

Tags: cron, raspbian, startup, reboot

I have this crontab `@reboot "/home/pi/Desktop/TV Scraper 2.0/run.sh"` set up and for whatever reason it doesn't seem to run the bash file on reboot.

Typing `"/home/pi/Desktop/TV Scraper 2.0/run.sh"` on the terminal actually runs the script, so I know it's correct.
This is what's inside run.sh just in case:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/pi/Desktop/TV Scraper 2.0"
node ./app.js
```

I've also tried using `@reboot root sh "/home/pi/Desktop/TV Scraper 2.0/run.sh"` as well, but it doesn't work either.

How can I move forward with this? My knowledge of Linux is very limited. All I need is to have some Node and Python3 scripts run on every reboot. On Windows that's such an easy task: I've tried CRON, rc.local and autostart, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `node` is not available via cronjob, since its containing directory is not in your `PATH` environment variable. When you execute the script manually, it's probably available via `PATH`.

An easy fix for this is to use the full path, which you can get by executing `which node`. The result should be something like `/usr/bin/node`. Then you can use that, instead of just `node`.

For debugging purpose you can also redirect stdout and stderr to a file, so the last line in your script would look like this:

```
/usr/bin/node ./app.js &>/tmp/cron-debug.log
```

If that doesn't fix it, i would rename the directory "TV Scraper 2.0" and replace the whitespace characters with something like an underscore. Directory and file names are less likely to cause problems if you avoid whitespaces.

Comment: neither changing "node" to "/usr/bin/node" or renaming the directory helped, typing the full path to run.sh on the terminal still works though, just like before.

Comment: Redirect stderr to `/tmp/omylogfile.log` to see what is happening.